# Import Excel files into SQL and vice versa using VB?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, excel

I will try my best to explain in detail what information I am looking for =)

I would like to know how I could go about making a simple little program in Visual Basic 2010 that has a button you click with drop down menu beside it to search for an excel or sql file on your computer and then you select it. Then you click a button saying "import into sql" or a different button saying "export to excel."

These buttons would of course do what they say... either importing the chosen excel file into sql  or exporting the sql file into excel.

Thank you so much for any help you might be able to offer.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I am very new to VB. I have done tons of research into searching on youtube and online for finding the answer, but I have been unsuccessful. I do not appreciate getting a "-1" for not researching when I have been looking online everyday for about two weeks.

Comment: I have found a code connected to a button that you can search for a file on your computer and then when you select it, it just opens the file itself. I have not found one that just selects it and then you can either choose to import it to sql or export it to excel. It should be fairly simple, but I have never found anything about it online.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the Business Intelligence Developer Studio that is built into Visual Studio 2008. It has a lot of developer tools that allow the transformation of data from SQL to flatfiles or vice versa. This is mostly done in the integration services area of the studio and is done through the creating of a ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) process. So to make a file that could be imported into excel you would save it as a flatfile that is seperated by a common delimeter that could then be hooked up to an excel sheet. Also, the BI development studio has not yet been updated to VS 2010 so you would have to get a copy of VS 2008.